# Video Stream Loop FFMPEG for YouTube, what is missing here?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, mp4, youtube

I am using FFMPEG for streaming 24/7 mp4 video on youtube.
The video is somewhere in 2 minutes, the stream starts but does not go on replay, what should I do?

I am using this code:

@echo off

d:

cd "D:\ffmpeg"

ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my_Secret_key